# Why ng-click function is executed twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I include a view with the `ng-include` functionnality:

```
<footer ng-include="view" ng-controller="searchPresenter" class="searchW"> </footer>
```

My controller defines:

```
$scope.view = 'search/minView.html';

$scope.search = function() {
    $scope.view = 'search/mainView.html';

    jQuery('html').click(function(event) {
        $scope.view = 'search/minView.html';
        console.log($scope.view)            
    });
};
```

The search function is used only into the first view included:

```
<div class="..." ng-click="search()">
    <i class="search icon"></i>
</div>
```

But when I click for the first time on the view I just load, the jQuery function is executed (I see it into the console) whereas it shouldn't.

And then when I click anywhere on my page, the console show me 2 new lines whereas only 1 event should be registred onto the `html` content.

Any idea?

Comment: because you keep binding a click event on every click. `jQuery('html').click(` does not override the other click events, it just appends to a *queue*.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle or plunk?  If you only bind jquery in the `search()` function, is it possible that is getting called twice?  Binding a click to the `html` element is weird, do you ever unbind it?  If not then you will bind it a second time when `search()` is called again.

Answer (score -1):

You should not have jQuery anywhere in your controller. You have an ng-click event already there, so adding the jQuery is not only a duplicate of the click event but totally not the Angular way of doing things. Your ng-click event is all you need to change the value of the $scope variable.

```
$scope.view = 'search/minView.html';

$scope.search = function() {
    $scope.view = 'search/mainView.html';
};
```